# PHP repeticion del mismo valor al hacer una consulta sql

Tags: php, array, sql

tengo la siguiente **base de datos**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito **displayear** todos los mensajes. Antes no tenia implementado el sistema de **etiquetas** y la consulta era la siguiente:

```
SELECT mensajes.id, titulo,contenido,createAt, usuario ,url_img
            FROM mensajes,usuarios   
            WHERE mensajes.creador = usuarios.id ORDER BY createAt DESC;
```

Ahora a parte de eso necesito las **etiquetas** que estan **relacionada** con cada una de los **mensajes**, por tanto recurri a la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT mensajes.id as 'id', mensajes.titulo as 'titulo',mensajes.contenido as 'contenido',mensajes.createAt as 'createAt', usuarios.usuario  as 'usuario',mensajes.url_img as 'url_img',etiquetas.nombre as 'etiqueta_nombre'
                FROM mensajes,usuarios,etiquetas,etiquetas_en_mensajes  
                    WHERE mensajes.creador = usuarios.id 
                            AND  mensajes.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_mensaje
                            AND  etiquetas.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta
                    ORDER BY createAt DESC;
```

Que me saca todo lo que quiero. Ahora transladando esto a **PHP** he formulado la siguiente **funcion**:

```
public function verTodosMensajes(){
    $conexion = $this->c->conectar();
$sql = "SELECT mensajes.id as 'id', mensajes.titulo as 'titulo',mensajes.contenido as 'contenido',mensajes.createAt as 'createAt', usuarios.usuario  as 'usuario',mensajes.url_img as 'url_img',etiquetas.nombre as 'etiqueta_nombre'
        FROM mensajes,usuarios,etiquetas,etiquetas_en_mensajes  
            WHERE mensajes.creador = usuarios.id 
                    AND  mensajes.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_mensaje
                    AND  etiquetas.id = etiquetas_en_mensajes.id_etiqueta
            ORDER BY createAt DESC; ";

    $result = $conexion->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows>0) {
        var_dump($result);
        return $result;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Ahora bien, si por **cada mensaje** obtengo de **0** a **n** **ETIQUETAS** como voy guardando un **array** de etiquetas por mensajes? Ya que tal cual esta ahi me repite todo por cada etiqueta, es decir, si tengo un **mensaje** que dice **hola** con las **etiquetas** `#saludo` `#programacion` `#ordenador` `#stackoverflow` me va a traer el **mismo** mensaje **4 veces** una por cada etiqueta asociada.

Comment: Buenas, no deberías utilizar dos consultas. Una para el mensaje y otra para las etiquetas.

Comment: Solo esoty intentando usar la de abajo, la de arriba ya no me vale, claro solo necesito una consulta