# PHP consulta para obtener las etiquetas de cada mensaje (Array de arrays)

Tags: php, base-de-datos, sql, select

Buenas estoy intentando obtener **todos los mensajes y sus etiquetas** de mi base de datos , mi `BD` la podréis encontrar en mi **otra pregunta relacionada** : [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/258129/php-repeticion-del-mismo-valor-al-hacer-una-consulta-sql).

Estoy intentando esto :

```
<?php 

    require_once '../conexion.php';

    //obtener todos los mensajes

    $c = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $c->conectar();


//================================================
//              OBTENER TODOS LOS MENSAJES
//================================================
    $sql = "SELECT id,titulo,contenido,createAt, url_img,creador FROM mensajes";
    var_dump($sql);



    $result = $conexion->query($sql);
    //$mensajes = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
   // var_dump($mensajes);
    $mensajes = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    if ($result) {


        foreach($result as $key ) { 
                // echo "ID = " . $key['id'] . "<br>";
             //     echo "TITULO = " . $key['titulo'] . "<br>";
             //     echo "CONTENIDO = " . $key['contenido'] . "<br>";
             //     echo "CREATE AT" . $key['createAt'] . "<br>";
             //     echo "CREADOR " . $key['creador'] . "<br>";
             //     echo "URL_IMG" . $key['url_img'] . "<br>";
             //     echo "<b>       ******************      </b>" ."<br>"   ;
        }
    }


echo "<br>=============================================================================<br>";
//================================================
//              OBTENER TODOS LAS ETIQUETAS DE CADA MENSAJE
//================================================

    // $sql = "SELECT * FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes";

    // $result = $conexion->query($sql);
    // $etiquetas_en_mensajes= mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    // if ($result) {
    //      foreach ($etiquetas_en_mensajes as $data) {
    //          echo $data['id'];
    //          echo $data['id_mensaje'];
    //          echo $data['id_etiqueta'];
    //      }
    // }




foreach ($result as $key) {
    $sql = " SELECT  * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '{$key['id']}');";
    echo $sql . "<br>";
    $result = $conexion->query($sql);
    while ($etiquetas = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    }
    // while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // }
}
```

Básicamente primero hago una consulta de todos los mensajes, luego guardo lo que recibo en un `array` mensajes, luego intento hacer un `select`
 de las etiquetas con ese **ID** pero no me deja , me dice : `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given`

Querría obtener un `array` que fuese algo así :

```
Mensajes {

          mensaje[
              id,
              titulo,
              contenido,
              creador,
              createAt,

              etiquetas[
                 id,
                 nombre
              ]
          ]

}
```

Mi idea de hacerlo, es así :

1. Obtengo los mensajes
2. Obtengo las etiquetas asociadas a cada mensaje
3. Guardarlo todo en un `array` para displayearlo fácilmente

**Display de `echo` de la segunda consulta (echo de la variable `$sql`)**

```
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '99');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '100');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '101');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '102');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '103');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '104');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '105');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '106');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '107');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '108');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '109');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '110');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '111');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '112');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '113');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '114');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '115');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '116');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '117');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '118');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '119');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '120');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '121');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '122');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '123');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '124');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '125');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '126');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '127');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '128');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '129');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '130');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '131');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '132');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '133');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '134');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '135');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '136');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '137');
SELECT * FROM etiquetas WHERE id = ( SELECT id_etiqueta FROM etiquetas_en_mensajes WHERE id_mensaje = '138');
```

Comment: Lo primero es que `$result` no es un recurso con los datos de la consulta, sino un boolenao (`FALSE` seguramente porque hubo un fallo en la consulta). Sin datos no puedes trabajar, por lo tanto debes revisar qué pasa con tu consulta o qué pasa con tu conexión, porque ahora mismo no estás obteniendo datos. Pon un `else`, más o menos así: `if ($result) {  /*codigo*/ } else { echo "Error: ".$conexion->error;}` Así sabrás qué pasa realmente.

Comment: La primera consulta me trae todos los mensajes bien, en la segunda intento obtener las etiquetas de cada mensaje, en este segunda parte hice un `echo` del `$sql` y la consultame la crea bien. Voy a editar la pregunta y pongo lo que me da el `echo`

Comment: Un echo de `$sql` no es prueba de nada, eso es sólo una cadena. Y hay más incoherencias en tu código. Estructúralo así:  `if ( $result = $conexion->query($sql) ) { $mensajes = mysqli_fetch_array($result); foreach($mensajes as $key ) { /*...*/  }  }else{ echo "Error: ".$conexion->error; }`

Comment: Al ponerlo de esa manera me dice que tengo `warnings`  `Illegal string offset 'id'` , me dice eso por cada campo

Comment: Prueba así: `if ( $result = $conexion->query($sql) ) { while ($key = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) { echo "ID = " . $key['id'] . "<br>";/*...etc */ } }else{ echo "Error: ".$conexion->error; }`